# How to hide certain plugins from other admins?

Tags: plugins

I'm running a WP site for a client (who has an admin account) and I'd like to hide certain plugins that I've installed. Is there a way to hide certain plugins (not all) from the list for specific users? I'm not interested in user *roles*, rather hiding certain plugins from specific user *names*. Thanks!

Comment: You want to hide plugin's from your client? Plugins that are running on your client's site? That sounds a bit sketchy.

Comment: For example, you want them to be able to see and configure, say, the bbPress plugin but not see (and tamper with) more geeky items, say, for htaccess control?